# Android studio WebView

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Всех приветствую! Начал писать приложение в android studio, WebView работает замечательно, но столкнулся с проблемой: скачивая файл с какого либо сайта он не загружается. В манифест добавил разрешение на работу с файловой системой `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`, но не помогло
java code:

```
public class Youtube extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);

        WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.loadUrl("https://pv-music.com/song/3938-hammali-navai-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B1%D0%B8-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8F");
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        } );
        webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {

        } );

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
webview.setDownloadListener(new DownloadListener() {       

    @Override
    public void onDownloadStart(String url, String userAgent,
                                    String contentDisposition, String mimetype,
                                    long contentLength) {
            DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(
                    Uri.parse(url));

            request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
            request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED); 
            request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "name file");
            DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
            dm.enqueue(request);

        }
    });
```

[Пример](https://androidride.com/android-webview-example-tutorial-kotlin-java-download-source-code/#android%20webview%20download%20file%20example)

Comment: Всё отлично работает, оказалось не было разрешения к хранилищу в телефоне. Спасибо!